# Finding size of the vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to read in numbers from a file and take the average of all the numbers but i'm unsure how to include the data.resize() and data.reserve() part into my code. I have to use resize and reserve. When I set current_size or max_size to data.size() to 0. Is there another way to find the size of the vector?

```
//   1) Read in the size of the data to be read (use type size_t)
//   2) Use data.resize() to set the current size of the vector
//   3) Use a for loop to read in the specified number of values,
//      storing them into the vector using a subscript
void readWithResize(vector<int> &data) {
    cout << "Using resize!" << endl;

    if (cin){
        size_t current_size;
        current_size = data.size();
        //cin >> current_size;
        cout << "current_size = " << current_size << endl;
        data.resize(current_size);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < current_size; i++){
            cin >> data[i];
            data.push_back(data[i]);
            cout << data[i] << " ";
            cout << current_size << endl;
        }

    }

//   1) Read in the size of the data to be read (use type size_t)
//   2) Use data.reserve() to set the maximum size of the vector
//   3) Use a for loop to read in the specified number of values,
//      storing them into the vector using data.push_back()
void reserve(vector<int> &data) {

    cout << "Using reserve!" << endl;

    if (cin){
        size_t max_size;
        //max_size = 12;

        data.reserve(max_size);
        cout << "max_size = " << max_size << endl;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < max_size; i++){
            cin >> data[i];
            data.push_back(data[i]);
            cout << data[i] << " ";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why would you use `reserve` here in the first place. And for that matter, why would you use a vector at all? To take a series of numbers and find their average you need 1. an accumulator, and 2. a counter.

Comment: You need resize, not reserve.  Reserve doesn't resize, so data[I] is invalid until you've pushed.  What you need to do is call resize and then remove the line with the push_back.

Comment: I've already implemented a function resize, this is another function that I have to write. Do i set max_size to a certain value? But I dont think I can because I dont know how many values are in the file.

Comment: I rolled back your edit, since it changed the question to something completely different. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother with `resize` and `reserve`. Read a value into a local variable of type `int`, then use `data.push_back()` to append it to the vector. The vector will resize itself as necessary:

```
int value;
while (std::cin >> value)
    data.push_back(value);
```

That will correctly handle any number of input values. But see the comment by @WhozCraig -- using a vector is overkill for the problem as stated.

Comment: Is there a way I can use 'resize' and 'reserve'?

Comment: @bellaxnov - only if you know how many elements you're going to end up with. For this code, you really don't need either of them.

Comment: If I were to use them, how would I find how many elements are there?

Comment: @bellaxnov - what problem are you trying to solve with `resize` or `reserve`? You can't tell, without reading the file, how many elements it holds. `vector` does a good job of managing memory as it expands, and that's the best you can do if you don't now in advance how much data you're going to have.

Comment: What exactly does reserve and resize do? What's the difference.

Comment: @bellaxnov See specific details here [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) and here [`std::vector::resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) .